# Why size of file .jpg is't same after read binary in C++?

Tags: c++, file, binary

this my pic.jpg
[image: Size of img: 11,126 bytes]

now i try to read the file, code to open files:

```
ifstream inputFile("pic.jpg", ios::in | ios::binary);
ofstream outFile("pic2.jpg", ios::out | ios::binary);
ofstream outFileTXT("pic2.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
```

then i read 256 bytes from inpuFile and write on to outFile and outFileTXT.

> the problem in the size, i mean: 
>   pic.jpg = 11,126  bytes. 
>   pic2.jpg = pic2.txt = 4,966  bytes.

this my buffer for read,

```
char buffer[257];
```

my code work well on *.txt (no problem).

> for 11,126 bytes needs 43 of reads (256 bytes) + what still ..

run 43 times ..

```
while (i++ < mod) {
    // read from binary file 256 byte
    in.read(buffer, 256);
    // init packet and save it in list by string.
    handler << buffer; // this line save buffer in list<string>
}
```

then i print my list to file.

> the idea is:  save buffer (size 256 byte) except the last one (118
>   bytes) into  list, witch mean's size of list must be 44, 43
>   (256 bytes) + 1 (118 bytes)
>
> then print list to file.

Comment: Maybe show your code?

Comment: Telling us what your code does doesn't actually tell us what it does, it tells us what you *think* it does. We need to see the code itself.

Comment: i cant add my code because is home work !
look to new add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a problem with this:

```
char buffer[257];

// ..

while (i++ < mod) {
    // read from binary file 256 byte
    in.read(buffer, 256);
    // init packet and save it in list by string.
    handler << buffer;
}
```

Specifically this:

```
handler << buffer;
```

Because `buffer` is a `char*` it will treat it as a *null terminated string* and it will output characters from the buffer until it finds a *zero*. What it won't do is output the whole buffer like you expect.

You can use `write()` for that:

```
while (i++ < mod) {
    // read from binary file 256 byte
    in.read(buffer, 256);
    // init packet and save it in list by string.
    handler.write(buffer, in.gcount()); // output all that was read
}
```

NOTE: Function `in.gcount()` tells us how many characters were read in the previous `in.read()` function (it won't always be exactly 256, it could be less if we reach the end).

Comment: this handler << buffer; is save buffer in list 
list<string> data.
all idea is take 256 bytes from file and save it in list !!
wick mean's the size of list must be 44, because we have 43*256 + what still.